# Unable to add sibling node into soap response

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd, wsdl

Hi everyone i need to generate soap response as following.I have generated it upto "GetTestDetailResult" node.But unable to add "country" as child of root node(GetTestDetailResponse).

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetTestDetailResponse>
      <GetTestDetailResult>
        <id>string</id>
        <fname>string</fname>
        <lname>string</lname>
      </GetTestDetailResult>
      <country>string</country>
      <age>int</age>
    </GetTestDetailResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My wsdl file is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="TestServiceService" targetNamespace="http://www.test.org/"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns:tns="http://www.test.org/"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:tns="http://www.test.org/"
                   attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
                   elementFormDefault="unqualified"
                   targetNamespace="http://www.test.org/">

            <xs:element name="GetTestDetail" type="tns:GetTestDetail"/>
            <xs:element name="GetTestDetailResponse" type="tns:GetTestDetailResponse"/>

            <xs:complexType name="GetTestDetail">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="email" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:complexType name="GetTestDetailResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element  minOccurs="1" name="GetTestDetailResult" type="tns:GetTestDetailResult"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:complexType name="GetTestDetailResult">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="fname" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lname" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="authFailed" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="soapMessage" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="GetTestDetail">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetTestDetail"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="GetTestDetailResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetTestDetailResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>


    <wsdl:portType name="TestServiceWsdlEndpointPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetTestDetail">
            <wsdl:input name="GetTestDetail" message="tns:GetTestDetail"/>
            <wsdl:output name="GetTestDetailResponse" message="tns:GetTestDetailResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="TestServiceWsdlEndpointBinding" type="tns:TestServiceWsdlEndpointPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

        <wsdl:operation name="GetTestDetail">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="GetTestDetail">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="getTestDetailResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="TestServiceWsdlEndpoint">
        <wsdl:port name="TestServiceWsdlPort" binding="tns:TestServiceWsdlEndpointBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/test/services/TestServiceWsdl"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

My responsive Java class is :-

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "testDetail", propOrder = {
        "id",
        "fname",
        "lname"

})

public class TestDetail {

    protected String id;
    protected String fname;
    protected String lname;

    protected String authFailed;
    protected String soapMessage;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String value) {
        this.fname = value;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String value) {
        this.lname = value;
    }

    public String getAuthFailed() {
        return authFailed;
    }

    public void setAuthFailed(String value) {
        this.authFailed = value;
    }

    public String getSoapMessage() {
        return soapMessage;
    }

    public void setSoapMessage(String value) {
        this.soapMessage = value;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Can you post your error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment yet (not enough rep) to clarify but when you say you can't add `country` as a child element of `GetTestDetailResponse` I assume that you are getting an XML invalid error.

Looking at your XML schema in the WSDL there is no `country` element defined

```
  <xs:element name="GetTestDetailResponse" type="tns:GetTestDetailResponse"/>
```

So changing the type to something like this should work:

```
  <xs:complexType name="GetTestDetailResponse">
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element  minOccurs="1" name="GetTestDetailResult" type="tns:GetTestDetailResult"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="country" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="age" type="xs:integer"/>
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I also added age, as that would have a similar problem.

Comment: Mike when ever i try to add the following lines application is not coming up.<xs:complexType name="GetTestDetailResponse">
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element  minOccurs="1" name="GetTestDetailResult" type="tns:GetTestDetailResult"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="country" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="age" type="xs:integer"/>
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

Comment: @sumit-verma When you say "not coming up" - do you get a specific error? Also did you add the annotations to your Java class?

Comment: Message: Error creating bean with name 'testServiceWsdlEndpointBean': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create()] threw ex
ception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I don't see the logs. Not sure where StackOverflow puts them. I recommend writing a test case for your JAXB objects and see if you that generates the XML expected. Based on the Java code posted, it looks like that is incomplete.

Comment: These are logs :- 
Message: Error creating bean with name 'testServiceWsdlEndpointBean': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create()] threw ex ception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I am assuming your wsdl is being generated automatically by API, so as Mike said, you have to add country, age etc within GetTestDetailResponse bean appropriately. Then your wsdl will have those elements.